# How to Acces PyCharm methods popup help? like IDLE

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

How do you access/turn on the pop up help with methods in PyCharm

[image]

all I can get is the quick documentation page...

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/viewing-method-parameter-information.html

Comment: `ctrl-p` is what you want

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you should post it as an answer, just add a bit more details.

Comment: @alecxe, added an answer using both methods

Comment: thanks Padraic, I've them working. Very helpful. Just a side note, but is there a way to include a little summary like IDLE has with the parameter pop up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up parameter info in **settings, IDE settings, editor, code completion** and under **Parameter info** check **`AutoPopup`** or  use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to get the parameter info.

To get the documentation check **AutoPopup Documentation** under **code completion** then  to get access the documentation use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> .

To get the external documentation press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>

pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> when you have not typed the opening paren will  give output like Idle, when you do it after with the opening or both parens typed you will get more extensive output